# Fill a new column based on whether two other cols are filled or empty

Tags: r

Here are some example data to illustrate my problem

```
dput(example)
structure(list(ID1 = c("", "abj6498", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"avl5803", "avl3030", "vz30775", "", "", "s883612", "avl7884", 
"", "", "avl7905", "", "", "", "", "ty68281", "", "", "z101246", 
"", "", "", "", "afh2697", "", "", "", "", "avl3037", "", "", 
"", "tw77193", "", "", "tw77053", "avl6702", "", "abj6256", "", 
"", "", ""), ID2 = c("", "and7457", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"j215736", "vz33290", "", "", "afh4845", "", "", "", "j215809", 
"", "", "", "", "ty69088", "", "", "j215813", "", "", "avl6192", 
"", "j215807", "", "avl5585", "", "", "avl5441", "", "", "", 
"ty70093", "", "", "tr43355", "avl3013", "", "afh3143", "", "", 
"", "")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have the dataframe `example` which has two cols, `ID1` and `ID2` all I need is a new column `present` based on whether or not either or both of `ID1` and `ID2` contain values

e.g.
If `ID1` is full but `ID2` is not then the new column `present` should have the value `1` and vice versa, if both contain a value then `present` would contain `2`

I have tried various methods using `tidyverse::mutate` and `if` statements but can't quite get the logic right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could  replace empty with `NA` and check with an `case_when` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(.=="", NA, as.character(.)))) %>% 
  mutate(present = case_when(!is.na(ID1) & !is.na(ID2) ~ 2,
                             !is.na(ID1) | !is.na(ID2) ~ 1))
```

output:

```
   ID1     ID2     present
   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
 1 NA      NA           NA
 2 abj6498 and7457       2
 3 NA      NA           NA
 4 NA      NA           NA
 5 NA      NA           NA
 6 NA      NA           NA
 7 NA      NA           NA
 8 NA      NA           NA
 9 avl5803 NA            1
10 avl3030 j215736       2
# … with 40 more rows
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks, then just for completeness I replaced the NA with 0 ```df[is.na(df)] <- 0```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowSums` to count number of values which are not empty in a row. This will return 0 for those values that are both empty, you can turn them to `NA` if needed.

```
example$present <- rowSums(example != '')
head(example, 10)

#       ID1     ID2 present
#1                        0
#2  abj6498 and7457       2
#3                        0
#4                        0
#5                        0
#6                        0
#7                        0
#8                        0
#9  avl5803               1
#10 avl3030 j215736       2
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution.